# defining page after issubmit

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im writting my first module in Prestashop. When I submit data in backoffice it loads the configuration page of my module. But I want to stay at the form. How can I achieve this?

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('toggleanswers')) {
        $id_answer = Tools::getValue('id_answer');
        if($this->toggleAnswer($id_answer)) {
            $this->_html .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Entry status changed'));
        }

        else {
            $this->_html .= $this->displayError(implode($this->_errors, '<br />'));
        }
}
```

This is how my function looks like. After Clicking on toggle it shouldn't return to configuration page... The url of my form looks like this: /index.php?controller=AdminModules&configure=questions&module_name=questions&id_question=1&updatequestions&token=ccd237618500f4c18f42d1a4fe971aa9

Comment: Where is located this if?

Comment: In a function named _postprocess() and this function is called in getContent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what do you want, you should change your code in this:

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('toggleanswers')) {
    $id_answer = Tools::getValue('id_answer');
    if($this->toggleAnswer($id_answer)) {
        Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', true).'&conf=6&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name.'&id_question='.$id_question.'&update_questions');
    } 
    else
    {
        $this->_html .= $this->displayError(implode($this->_errors, '
'));
    }
}
```

If you have managed good the post process and if is all ok you should redirected on the form of your 'question' with default message of changed status otherwise it will display the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped a lot. It worked for me like that: Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false) . 
    '&configure=' . $this->name .
    '&module_name=' . $this->name .
    '&id_question=' . $id_question .
    '&updatequestions' . 
    '&token=' . Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'));